# Django Postgres Aggregate Functions

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to use aggregate functions on a column in my model.

Following is my model:-

```
class ShipmentWeightMapping(models.Model):
    weight = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'weights')
```

Here is my aggregation query:-

```
shipment_weight_obj = ShipmentWeightMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id__in = shipment_id_list).aggregate(Avg('weight'),Max('weight'),Min('weight'),Sum('weight'))
total_weight = shipment_weight_obj['weight__sum']
max_weight = shipment_weight_obj['weight__max']
min_weight = shipment_weight_obj['weight__min']
avg_weight = shipment_weight_obj['weight__avg']
```

The above code runs with MySQL as DB but returns an error when used with postgres it returns an error:-

```
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("data_shipmentweightmapping"."weight") AS "weight...
[Tue Jul 08 04:05:38 2014] [error]                ^
[Tue Jul 08 04:05:38 2014] [error] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How come is this happening? I know that weight is a `char` field and I'm adding a `char` field, which I suppose is not allowed in postgres, but how can alter my query so that it works ? Also , why it works in MySql and not in postgres

Answer (score 2):

> I know that weight is a char field and I'm adding a char field, which I suppose is not allowed in postgres, but how can alter my query so that it works ?

Either:

- Use a suitable data type for `weight` - probably `float4` or `float8` (`double precision`), but maybe `numeric` if you need it; or
- Cast to a numeric type before aggregation, so you run `SUM( CAST("data_shipmentweightmapping"."weight" AS float4))`

> Also , why it works in MySql and not in postgres

MySQL lets you do all sorts of crazy things that PostgreSQL doesn't. Like adding a bunch of text fields together and implicitly converting them to numbers. Inserting zero as a date. Comparing nulls for equality.

If you run MySQL in STRICT ANSI mode (which you should always do) then it's a lot more sensible about the weird things it lets you do - or doesn't.

Comment: How can I do it in Django ORM?

Comment: @user1162512 Ideally: change the column type to the correct type in your models. If you mean "how do I type-cast a column in a Django ORM query" ... no idea. I suggest posting a Django-specific question on that and linking back to this one for context.